# Was My computer vulnerable to VLC subtitle hack?

Tags: ubuntu, subtitles

In May, a vulnerability has been discovered in VLC and other media players (like kody and popcorn time ...). They explain in the article https://fossbytes.com/subtitle-hack-affects-millions-device-vlc-kodi-fix-released/ that the vulnerabilities has been fixed by VLC in that time.

But when I check the VLC changelog using the command `apt changelog vlc`, (I am using Ubuntu 17.04 by the way), I am getting this :

> vlc (2.2.4-14ubuntu2.1) zesty-security; urgency=high
>
> - SECURITY UPDATE: Crash due to Out-of-Bound Heap Memory Write (LP: #1693893)
>
>   - fix-CVE-2017-10699.patch
>   - CVE-2017-10699
>   - SECURITY UPDATE: Fix potential out of bound reads
>   - fix-CVE-2017-8310.patch
>   - CVE-2017-8310
>   - SECURITY UPDATE: Fix invalid double increment
>   - fix-CVE-2017-8311.patch
>   - CVE-2017-8311
>   - SECURITY UPDATE: Fix potential heap buffer overflow
>   - fix-CVE-2017-8312.patch
>   - CVE-2017-8312
>   - SECURITY UPDATE: ParseJSS: fix out-of-bounds read
>   - fix-CVE-2017-8313.patch
>   - CVE-2017-8313
>
> -- Simon Quigley   Sun, 09 Jul 2017 22:37:06 -0500

If you notice the date, this vulnerabilities were fixed in the Ubuntu repository on the 09 Jul 2017, although the article indicates that VLC fixed this vulnerabilities in May 2017.

So, was my computer vulnerable to this hack this whole time ? and if so, which fault is it ? Was it the fault of VLC team that didn't really push the fixes, or was is it the community team fault that didn't patch the VLC version available in the universe Ubuntu repositories ?

**NOTE** : I am not criticizing this two wonderful teams (Ubuntu and VLC), they are doing an excellent job, and creating excellent softwares. I just wanna understand what happened here. Thanks.